# Check if there are more documents when implementing pagination with skip() and limit()

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, tornado-motor

I'm using Motor, which uses pymongo under the hood, to implement pagination for some documents. Here is what I have:

```
    rows = (
        db.programs
        .find(query)
        .sort("_id")
        .skip(page * page_count)
        .limit(page_count)
    )
```

What's the recommended way to check if there are more documents?

`rows.next_object()` is always returning `None`, even when there are more documents to fetch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit to `page_count+1` documents. If you get that many, you know there is another page of results to show. If you get `page_count` or fewer, you are on the last page.

Comment: Simple and smart.